# What's the difference between “It had snowed in the night, so the bus didn't arrive.” & “It snowed in the night, so the bus didn't arrive.”?

Tags: tense, verbs, past-tense, past-perfect, past-continuous

What's the difference between

> 1. It had snowed in the night, so the bus didn't arrive.
> 2. It snowed in the night, so the bus didn't arrive.

I think in the first sentence there is causality and the second it seems the two main clauses are unrelated.
Which one is preferable? Is there really a difference in meaning? Is the second sentence grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

In the first sentence,

- It had snowed in the night...

  the past perfect "had snowed" implies that the night has finished, and thus implies that the bus that was supposed to arrive *in the morning* did not arrive *in the morning*.

In the second sentence,

- It snowed in the night...

the night *might not be done yet*, from the writer's point of view, and the bus that "didn't arrive" might have been expected *sometime during the night*. Not necessarily, buf maybe.

If one wanted to more clearly suggest that both the snow and the "not arriving" occurred on the previous night, one could say:

- It had snowed in the night, so the bus **had not** arrived.

The interpretation also depends on how long you think the writer might have been willing to wait for a delayed bus before declaring that it "didn't arrive" (or hadn't).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there really a difference in meaning?

I don't see any real difference in meaning between the two sentences. I know of two actions "it snowed" and "the bus didn't arrive" and I know that the snow caused the bus not to arrive.

> Is the second sentence grammatically correct?

Both are grammatically correct. The only difference being that the first uses the "[past perfect](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/past-perfect-tense/)" to conjugate *to snow*, the latter uses the "[past simple](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/simple-past-tense/)" tense.

> Which one is preferable?

Either. Your choice.

> The second it seems the two main clauses are unrelated

I disagree because of your use of the word "so". If this was omitted, the sentences *could be* unrelated. Though of course, due to their proximity, I'd take them to be related anyway.

> It snowed in the night [, that's why it's so cold today). The bus didn't arrive, [because the driver slept in!]